# How does the compactness property help us show a subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, compactness

We have a compact subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ and we want to show that this implies that $A$ is closed.

Let $y \in A$ and $y \in A^c$. For each $y \in A$, we can take open neighbourhoods $U_y$ of $y$ and $V_y$ of $x$ such that $U_y \bigcap V_y = \emptyset$. Because $A$ is compact we only need a finite number of the $U_y$s to cover $A$. So let $U = \bigcup_{i=1}^N U_i$ and $V = \bigcap_{i=1}^N V_i$. Then $U$ and $V$ are open and $U \bigcap V = \emptyset$.

Now $x \in V \subseteq A^c$ and as $x$ is arbitrary $A^c$ is open. Hence $A$ is closed.

What I don't get is how does the compactness assumption help us here? Why can't we just take an infinite number of $U_y$s that cover $A$? That is let $U = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_y$ and $V = \bigcap_{i \in I} V_y$ where $I$ is an infinite index set.

Then we can still say $x \in V \subseteq A^c$ and as $x$ is arbitrary $A^c$ is open. Hence $A$ is closed?

Comment: The intersection of infinitely many open sets need not be open.

Comment: For instance, the intersection of open intervals of the form $(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ as $n$ runs from $1$ to $\infty$ is the (non-open) singleton $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: The compactness allows us to work with the finite intersection rather than the infinite one; once we can do that, we are able to say that $V$ is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not so much an answer to the question, as a commentary on the unnecessary use
of the axiom of choice in the proof given by the author of the question. I am doing this because
this kind of abuse of AC is typical.

We can avoid using AC in the following way.

Suppose we have a compact subset $A$ of a Hausdorff space $X$ (every metric space has a Hausdorff topology); we shall prove that $A$ is closed. Let $x\in X\setminus A$. We claim that some open neighborhood of $x$ is contained in $X\setminus A$; this will prove that $A$ is closed.

Let $I$ be the set of all pairs of open sets $(U,V)$ where $x\in U$ and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. For each $i=(U,V)\in I$ we let $N_i:=U$ and $W_i:=V$. If a point $y\in X$ is different from $x$, then
there exists $i=(U,V)\in I$ such that $y\in V=W_i$, because $X$ is a Hausdorff space.
Therefore $\bigcup_{i\in I}W_i=X\setminus\{x\}$. In particular, $A$ is contained in the union $\bigcup_{i\in I}W_i$.
Since $A$ is compact, it is contained in the union $\bigcup_{k\in K}W_k$ for some finite subset $K$ of $I$.
Then the point $x$ has an open neighborhood  $\bigcap_{k\in K}N_k$ that is disjoint with the open
neighborhood $\bigcup_{k\in K}W_k$ of the set $A$, and hence is disjoint with the set $A$ itself.
Our claim is proved.

Comment: There is no reason to make a fuss over the use of $\mathsf{AC}$, *especially* in topology. The usual proof is nice and intuitive, and unless one is specifically interested in foundational questions, which is not the case in elementary topology courses, there is no need to bugger it up with unnecessary technical details.